# Maintaining Session in Android to avoid Reconnecting Again and Again

Tags: android, performance, web-services, session

I want to know about the session Management in android application, Like In My android application I am using single server for getting the different information using REST APIs so my application make different calls to the server and each time It connect to the server and then get the data. So as far as I think, the application should connect to server first time only then next time application download data directly without reconnecting to the server because this thing make my application more faster.Thanks in Advance

Comment: best answer i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values/3624358#3624358

Comment: @jenuine thanks for your reply, but my Question is different because in the Given link application storing the data in preference, so the saved value will be avaialble next time, while I am looking to maintain session with server from android application , so that I can make REST api call faster.